# Thread WaitOne and ReleaseMutex C# List Reference vs copy all the values

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

In C# I would like to know the performance difference of `referencing a List` variable versus `copying all the values` using the code

`new List<>(otherlist)`

I have a thread in which I hold few MySQL queries as `List<MySqlCommand>` and also have a `SELECT` query which needs to be executed for every 30 seconds.

This `List<MySqlCommand>` is going to be updated from other codes while the thread is running.

For that I have written a lock code to copy the values from the main `List` to a local `List` as follows, inside  `protected override void ThreadFunction()`

```
Mutex lock= new Mutex();
.....
.....
lock.WaitOne();
List<MySqlCommand> currentSql = sqlHistory;
sqlHistory = new List<MySqlCommand>();
lock.ReleaseMutex();
```

I feel like every 30 seconds I am creating a new object instance

My question is, what if we do like this

```
Mutex lock= new Mutex();
.....
.....
lock.WaitOne();
List<MySqlCommand> currentSql = new List<MySqlCommand>(sqlHistory);
sqlHistory.Clear();
lock.ReleaseMutex();
```

Does copying decreases the performance or memory leak. which one will be a better approach.

Comment: In the second example, you're also creating a new list every time, except that you're also copying all the contents of another list. Why do you expect it to be faster?

Comment: Also, your code is confusing. What is this `ReleaseMutex` method? In the first example, isn't it an error to call `ReleaseMutex` on the new list rather than `currentSql`?

Comment: Why not use one of the [thread safe collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @KevinGosse `ReleaseMutex()` should be called on the object for which `WaitOne()` is called

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a 'best' or fastest way to do it, when executing it every 30 seconds. Both do not leak. But for logic; It sounds stupid to create a new list and copy the items.

You should choose the most readable way. But, I'd rather use the `lock`, because it uses the try/finally. Whenever an exception is thrown, you need to ensure the lock is released.

I mostly use this construction for batch processing:

```
MySqlCommand[] copy;

lock(_sqlHistory)
{
    copy = _sqlHistory.ToArray();
    _sqlHistory.Clear();
}

foreach(var command in copy)
{
    // ...
}
```

Next question, why create spikes with executing it every 30 seconds?